# Error executing Caffeine CacheBuilder configuration class when migrated to Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, caffeine

I am migrating to Kotlin CacheBuilder, a Spring Boot configuration class for CaffeineCache

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
open class CacheBuilder {
    @Bean
    open fun caffeineConfig(): Caffeine<Any, Transaction> {
        return CacheConfigurationHandler.transactionCaffeineConfig
    }

    @Bean
    open fun cacheManager(caffeine: Caffeine<Any, Any>): CacheManager {
        val caffeineCacheManager = CaffeineCacheManager("TransactionCache")
        caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine)
        return caffeineCacheManager
    }
}
```

when I run the application I get the error:

*Parameter 0 of method cacheManager in com.initialization.CacheBuilder required a bean of type 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine' that could not be found.*

It is like the caffeineConfig method is not creating the Caffeine bean and Spring can not find it to pass to the cacheManager method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring (last used it in the xml days), but the types `<Any, Transaction>` and `<Any, Any>` don't match. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Using <Any, Any> or <Any, Transaction> in both methods solved the issue!